# How to set transparency color of the WPF Window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, transparency

Is there any way to set one specific color to be transparent for the whole WPF window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to.  Transparency in WPF doesn't work using mask colors like in Winforms- just set the background to Transparent, and AllowsTransparency to true.  If you want different shaped windows, you can use the technique described here: http://devintelligence.com/2007/10/shaped-windows-in-wpf/

Answer (score 4):

We can make a [transparent WPF window](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2007/06/20/transparent-windows-in-wpf-2/) by using a XAML like follows.

```
<Window x:Class="SeeThru.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SeeThru" Height="300" Width="300"
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent">
......
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. WPF supports alpha-channel transparency, not bitmap mask transparency.

There are people who have attempted to [work around this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/06/20/implementing-a-custom-bitmapsource.aspx), but only on a per-image basis.